# Setting up zend 1.12 on Windows server (Forbidden 403)

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, vhosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias test.com

    DocumentRoot "D:/web/test/public"
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html

    <Directory "D:/web/test/public">
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hi, I have a vhost above but I still get an error `403(Forbidden access)`.
I've tried adding `Require all granted` but it does not work.
Directory index forbidden by Options directive: D:/web/test/public

Comment: 1) how do you access this host (what exactly do you write into the address bar)? 2) folder permissions

Comment: BTW. thank you i already resolved this.